# No of detected face is 0 in distant image andorid

Tags: android, image-processing, face

I am capturing image by camera. I have the following image:

I am trying to detect face from this image by the following code:

```
private Bitmap detectFaces(Bitmap imageBitmap) {  


        Bitmap background_image = imageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
        if((1==(background_image.getWidth()%2))){
            background_image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background_image, 
                background_image.getWidth()+1, background_image.getHeight(), false);
        }
        imageBitmap = background_image.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
             int width = imageBitmap.getWidth();  
             int height = imageBitmap.getHeight();  

             // Call face detector object  
             FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(width, height,  
                       10);  
             Face[] faces = new Face[10];  
             Bitmap bitmap565 = imageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
                     //Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);  

             Paint ditherPaint = new Paint();  
             Paint drawPaint = new Paint();  

             // Set properties of the rectangle that should appear for a detected  
             // face  
             ditherPaint.setDither(true);  
             drawPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);  
             drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  
             drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);  

             // Create a canvas and draw the imagebitmap over the canvas  
             Canvas canvas = new Canvas();  
             canvas.setBitmap(bitmap565);  
             canvas.drawBitmap(imageBitmap, 0, 0, ditherPaint);  

             // trigger the face detector function and store the number of faces  
             // detected as int paramter faceFound  
             int facesFound = detector.findFaces(bitmap565, faces); 

             // This parameters find the midpoint, eyeDistance and confidence in  
             // a face  
             PointF midPoint = new PointF();  
             float eyeDistance = 0.0f;  
             float confidence = 0.0f;  
             Log.i("FaceDetector", "Number of faces found: " + facesFound);  
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number of faces found: " + facesFound,
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             if (facesFound > 0) {  

                  // Select detected faces, one after one  
                  for (int index = 0; index < facesFound; ++index) {  
                       // Get mid point, eye distance and confidence of the face  
                       faces[index].getMidPoint(midPoint);  
                       eyeDistance = faces[index].eyesDistance();  
                       confidence = faces[index].confidence();  
                       Log.i("FaceDetector", "Confidence: " + confidence  
                                 + ", Eye distance: " + eyeDistance  
                                 + ", Mid Point: (" + midPoint.x + ", " + midPoint.y  
                                 + ")");  
                       try {  

                            // Draw a rectange depending upon face parameters.  
                            // Kindly note that this is just for displaying the  
                            // rectangle  
//                            canvas.drawRect((float) midPoint.x - (eyeDistance * 2),  
//                                      (float) midPoint.y - (eyeDistance * 2),  
//                                      (int) midPoint.x + (eyeDistance * 2),  
//                                      (int) midPoint.y + (eyeDistance * 2), drawPaint);  

                            // And this is for cropping the detected face from the  
                            // image  
                            Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap,  
                                      (int) (midPoint.x - (eyeDistance * 2)),  
                                      (int) (midPoint.y - (eyeDistance * 2)),  
                                      (int) (eyeDistance * 4),  
                                      (int) (eyeDistance * 4));  

                            bitmap565 = croppedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);

                       } catch (Exception e) {  
                            /*  
                             * Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),  
                             * "Too many faces/face size is too small, kindly go back and try again..."  
                             * , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                             */  
                       }  
                  }  
             }  
             else
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Face is not detected",
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             return bitmap565 ;  

   }
```

But the code says that the detected face is 0. Actually when I am capturing image from a distance, it says the no of detected face is 0. Why? How can I detect face from image captured from a distance of 1 meter? Any advice is of great help.